# Google Maps DrawingManager initiate draw after pin drop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a method which will initiate the draw of an object with the Google Map API draw library? I have the following workflow

1. User doubleclicks on map
2. Pin is dropped
3. Circle is drawn using the DrawingManager

However between #2 and #3 there is an additional click needed. Is there anyway around this extra click?

http://jsfiddle.net/gu2wD/9/

```
   function createCircle() {

          //create drawing manager to draw circle on map
          var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
          drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
          drawingControl: true,
          drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
              google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE
            ]
          },
          circleOptions: {
            strokeColor: '#0099FF',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#0099FF',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: map,
                center: marker.getPosition(),
                editable: true,
                radius: 50
          }
        });

      drawingManager.setMap(map);

      google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function (circle) {
        popUpPinInfo(marker, circle.radius, map);
      google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'radius_changed', function () {
        popUpPinInfo(marker, circle.radius, map);
      });
    });



    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
              drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    });


    }
```

I think it is really close. However when I use the drawing manager(which allows me to pick up the change events on the radius) the circle doesnt start immediately. causing an additional click

Comment: your current code would be interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker), I don't see an event you could use to detect when a marker has been dropped. I thought there was a chance the `position_changed` event might be fired, but this only seems to happen when you set the marker to draggable and physically move it.

I think your best bet, therefore is to use a `setTimeout` in your double click handler to delay the drawing of the circle until the marker has dropped into place. Something like this (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gu2wD/)):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function() { 
    createMarker();
    setTimeout(createCircle, 500);
});

function createMarker() {
  // create the marker
}

function createCircle() {
  // create the circle       
}
```

**EDIT:**

@geocodezip has kindly provided an improved [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gu2wD/3/) in which the marker is placed at the site of the double click and the circle is editable.

Comment: In the workflow I have the line after the marker is dropped because I start the DrawingManager in the same listner for 'dblclick'

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is the functionality in the fiddle not what you're looking for?

Comment: My expectation is that the marker would be placed at the location of the double click and be editable [modified fiddle (only allows one marker/circle)](http://jsfiddle.net/gu2wD/3/)

Comment: Yeah fair enough, I just wanted to knock together a quick demo but yours is probably closer to what OP wants - though it's still not clear to me exactly what he's looking for.

Comment: geocodezip and net.uk I apreciate the posts. Geocode that is exactly what I am looking foR!

Comment: Can you pick up the 'circlecomplete' and 'radius_changed' if you arent using the drawingManager? Was able to get this to work. http://jsfiddle.net/gu2wD/4/

Comment: There's no circlecomplete event as far as I can make out :- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle. radius_changed works okay (see updated http://jsfiddle.net/LKQx6/). Please mark the answer as correct if it helped you out :)